# Swift & Firebase: Accessing Information

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app that allows notes to be shared. I'm having trouble with the Firebase database and feel that the amount of lines of code I am using to get information the user needs is more than I actually need and on top of that doesn’t work. Below is a screenshot of my database and a show of the code I’ve used. There are 3 different account types in my app. Parent, Child, and Other.

- The Child can only see their own notes
- The Parent can see everyone who’s written notes in for their code
- The Other is supposed to see their notes and the parents notes per
  code.

I am attempting to show the users whose notes can be seen in a collection view. So far it works for Parents and Children but not for the 'Other' which I am trying to fix.

This is my database. Right now, a Parent makes the account which generates a unique code. Then an Other or Child can join by typing the code in on a ViewController. For a child account it will automatically add the code to the account of the child in the user section and for the Other it is supposed to make a new section (I added a picture of what it looked like before I changed it). All users that have a certain code are added to the code section under that code.

```
 {
  "codes" : {
    "ParVWb" : {
      "totalUsers" : 2,
      "users" : {
        "VWbSR8qQyWd9deka6tgbxFC9ahs1" : {
          "numberofNotes" : 0
        },
        "qm12qgkWfdbtSMMx58wIrxKuLKh1" : {
          "numberofNotes" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "JN47TBdI4EYX0NvoSHN21o1xFH92" : {
      "email" : "other1@restart.mocs",
      "fullName" : "Other 1 Name",
      "type" : "Other",
      "uid" : "JN47TBdI4EYX0NvoSHN21o1xFH92"
    },
    "VWbSR8qQyWd9deka6tgbxFC9ahs1" : {
      "code" : "ParVWb",
      "email" : "parentemail@restart.mocs",
      "fullName" : "Parent Name",
      "type" : "Parent",
      "uid" : "VWbSR8qQyWd9deka6tgbxFC9ahs1"
    },
    "qm12qgkWfdbtSMMx58wIrxKuLKh1" : {
      "code" : "ParVWb",
      "email" : "childname@restart.mocs",
      "fullName" : "Child Name",
      "type" : "Child",
      "uid" : "qm12qgkWfdbtSMMx58wIrxKuLKh1"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Picture of Other User section]
I used to have the use section look like this but now because of the large amount of reference blocks, it doesn't run the part that adds the "codes" section to the 'Other' user.

This is the function I have in my CollectionViewController that obtains all the needed users depending on the currentUser type.

```
func fetchConnections() {
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)

        if user.type == "Parent" {

            let code = user.code as? String
            let codeRef = databaseRef.child("codes").child(code!).child("users")

            codeRef.observe(.value, with: { (codeSnapshot) in

                if let users = codeSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        for user in users {
                            if let dict = user.value as? [String: Any] {
                                let userInformation = cellInfo(uid: user.0, numberofNotes: (dict["numberofNotes"] as? Int)!, code: self.code)
                                self.userCollection.append(userInformation)
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        } else if user.type == "Child" {
            let code = user.code
            self.ref.child("codes").child(code!).child("users").child(self.userID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    print(user.key, (dict["numberofNotes"] as? Int)!)
                    let userInformation = cellInfo(uid: (user.key as? String)!, numberofNotes: (dict["numberofNotes"] as? Int)!, code: "code")
                    self.userCollection.append(userInformation)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })


        } else if user.type == "Other" {

            self.ref.child("users").child(self.userID!).child("codes").observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
                if let codes = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    for code in codes {
                        if code.key == "numberofCodes" {
                            print("ignore")
                        } else { // If it's an actual code
                            self.ref.child("users").child(code.0).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (codeSnap) in
                                let user = User(snapshot: codeSnap)

                                let codetoFetch = user.code

                                self.ref.child("codes").child(codetoFetch!).child("users").child(self.userID!).observe(.value, with: {(codeSnapshot) in
                                    if let users = codeSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                            for user in users {
                                                if let dict = user.value as? [String: Any] {

                                                   let userInformation = cellInfo(uid: code.0, numberofNotes: (dict["numberofNotes"] as? Int)!, code: self.code)
                                                    //self.userCollection.append(userInformation)
                                                    //self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                })

                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

How can I obtain all of the codes that the 'Other' is a part of and all of the UID's & NumberofNotes for the 'Parents' of that code so that I can put them into the collectionView? (This code works for Parent and Child but if the way I'm doing it is long and ineffective please let me know.)

Comment: You've included pictures of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: The question has been updated